# Lucene.net create+lock errors in ASP.NET

Tags: .net, asp.net, lucene.net

**-Edit- Important: I updated the code to not use obsoluete functions. Now only the NoSuchDirectoryException issue remains**

Edit: NOTE i can bypass the NoSuchDirectoryException by creating the folder in a winform app and copy it. However i still have a LockObtainFailedException issue if i dont shut down properly.

I have an issue with (Lucene.net 2.9.2)[https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/lucene/lucene.net/tags/]. It throws a lock exception. After poking around i notice these things.

1. My code below works in an app bit when calling in Application_Start i get a NoSuchDirectoryException.
2. Not closing the writer (as my code doesnt do below) i WILL get a LockObtainFailedException with the message
   `Lock obtain timed out: SimpleFSLock@<FULL_PATH>` from either app or asp.net

These thread hinted when spawning threads they get less permissions then i do (but! my main thread has problems as well...) and one solution is to impersonate IIS. I am using visual studios 2010. I am not sure how full blown it is but my attempt to impersonate it failed.

So my question is how do i have lucene create the directory and not throw an exception if dont close the writer for some reason (such as power going out)?

[Why is my Lucene index getting locked?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2341163/why-is-my-lucene-index-getting-locked/2499285#2499285)
[Lucene.Net and I/O Threading issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1123517/lucene-net-and-i-o-threading-issue/1123981#1123981)

```
    static IndexWriter writer = null;
    static void lucene_init()
    {
        bool create = false;
        //I now use a full path. I still get NoSuchDirectoryException 
        //string dirname = "LuceneIndex_z";
        if (System.IO.Directory.Exists(dirname) == false)
            create = true;

        var directory = FSDirectory.GetDirectory(dirname);
        var analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer();
        writer = new IndexWriter(directory, analyzer, create);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> So my question is how do i have lucene
>   create the directory and not throw an
>   exception if dont close the writer for
>   some reason (such as power going out)?

I suppose you refer to unlocking the directory, not creating it. If writer had not finished it well, it should be in a locked (and ofcourse created) state. 
If its so, have you not tried unlocking it ???

Answer (score 0):

I just implemented a test server that needs to connect to another server where the lucene index resides. To further complicate the issue, both machines are AWS EC2, but on separate Amazon accounts.

After I got the necessary network settings correct across the accounts, I could share the lucene folder and browse to it (in RDP) and then set as a mapped network drive. So far so good.

This is where I go the same **NoSuchDirectoryException** when browsing to the site on the test server. After some fiddling, I found that the problem lay with the site's **appPool** in **IIS**. Once I set the appropriate **permissions** on the **appPool**, it worked